# Play two sounds with different volumes on iOS

Tags: ios, audio, volume

I am developing an application that has a **background music** and a timer that notifies user with an **alarm**.
Now the problem is when the app is launched user turns device's volume down (**background music**), but I want the **alarm** to be loud enough, preferably at the same level as the device's ringtone/alarm.
(Right now I am using `AVAudioPlayer`)

Any suggestion ?

Comment: did you try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32683188/play-sound-on-ios-9-in-silent-mode

Comment: Dear @PavloShadov, my problem is not silent-mode but it's the low volume on the device; but I want the alarm sound to be loud.